# Vertically repeating image filling space in between a header and a link

Tags: css, stylesheet, frontend

I'm stumped on this one. What's the most elegant/efficient way to make this happen?  I've got an `h3` to the left, the repeating symbol/image ("::::::"), and then a link. This occurs between several `h3`/link areas throughout the site.

Also note, I'm using the twelve column schema, specifically Foundation.

[image: example]

Comment: ahhh, a background on the text elements. brilliant :)

Comment: You'll have to wait for him to repost his comment as an answer in order to accept it.

Comment: I've reposted the comment as an answer. Also, you should check the other questions you've asked and make sure there are no potential answers that you could mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a background element with the repeating symbol and a width of 100%, and then set a white background to the text and place it over the background.

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="text1">Featured Courses</div>
   <div id="text2">See All Courses</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#wrapper{
   width:100%;
   background:url(image.png) repeat-x;
   height:20px;
}
#text1, #text2{
   background-color:#fff
   padding:5px
   height:10px;
}
#text1{
   float:left
}
#text2{
   float:right
}
```

This is probably not *exactly* what you need but you get the idea.